# Asynchronous posix_fallocate()?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, posix

I'd like to reserve space for a file being downloaded, like `posix_fallocate()` does.

Is there an asynchronous API as well, or do I need to sacrifice a background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an asynchronous version of `posix_fallocate`.

You do need to invoke this function in another thread to avoid blocking the current thread.